# aggregation of a mixed used column - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, types, aggregate

I've got a pandas dataframe with two object columns of FEATURE and FEATURE_VALUE, representing the name of the feature and value of the feature respectively. while FEATURE_VALUE is an object column, in reality it contains types int, float and str. I'd like to do aggregation on FEATURE_VALUE based on FEATURE, but int and float values in str format behave differently than when in int and float formats. I was wondering if there is a way to write a labmda function or a function that could convert values of FEATURE_VALUE to float based on the value of FEATURE at the time of aggregation, as opposed to having to generate separately converted columns first.
in the example below, FEATURE values of A and C have numeric values, while FEATURE B has string value.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'FEATURE': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'FEATURE_VALUE': ['9', 'A', '2', '11', 'G', ' 100', '9']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

  FEATURE FEATURE_VALUE
0       A             9
1       B             A
2       A             2
3       A            11
4       B             G
5       C           100
6       C             9

    #desired_output after aggregate:
df_agg
FEATURE  MIN_FEATURE_VALUE  MAX_FEATURE_VALUE
   A             2                 11
   B             A                  G
   C             9                100
```

please note that using normal min/max aggregation on FEATURE_VALUE doesn't work because
'100' > '9'  is False
but 100 > 9 is True

I have over 200 unique FEATURE values and I know which features are float/int and which ones are string. is there a way to do the data conversion in one go during aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Firstly make use of `pd.to_numeric()` and make string numerical values to actual numerical value:

```
df['FEATURE_VALUE']=pd.to_numeric(df['FEATURE_VALUE'],errors='coerce').fillna(df['FEATURE_VALUE'])
```

Finally use `groupby()`+`agg()`(with named tuples):

```
out=df.groupby('FEATURE',as_index=False).agg(MIN_FEATURE_VALUE=('FEATURE_VALUE','min'),MAX_FEATURE_VALUE=('FEATURE_VALUE','max'))
```

OR

via `pivot_table()`:

```
out=df.pivot_table('FEATURE_VALUE','FEATURE',aggfunc=['min','max'])
out.columns=out.columns.map('_'.join).str.upper()
out=out.reset_index()
```

output of `out`:

```
  FEATURE   MIN_FEATURE_VALUE   MAX_FEATURE_VALUE
0   A       2.0                 11.0
1   B       A                   G
2   C       9.0                 100.0
```

Comment: All I was missing was the first bit in conversion! thank you, this was super helpful.